# Rewriting function

Tags: functions

Given function
$$
f(x) = \frac{-2 + 2 \sqrt{x+1}}{x}
$$
and
$$
g(x) = \frac{2}{1+\sqrt{x+1}}
$$
Prove that $f(x) = g(x)$ where $x\neq 0$.

This question is from a 2018 examen in the Netherlands. I tried rewriting f(x) as follows:
$$
f(x) = \frac{-2 + 2 \sqrt{x+1} * \sqrt{x+1}}{x*\sqrt{x+1}}
$$
$$
f(x) = \frac{-2 + 2(x+1)}{x*\sqrt{x+1}}
$$
$$
f(x) = \frac{-2 + 2x + 2}{x*\sqrt{x+1}}
$$
$$
f(x) = \frac{2x}{x*\sqrt{x+1}}
$$
$$
f(x) = \frac{2}{\sqrt{x+1}}
$$

However, I can't find a way to get to the $h(x)$ function where the denominator has a 1 + still.

EDIT:
Just as I post this I notice that I made a mistake in the first step. By not multiplying against the whole numerator. I'll leave the question open anyways.

Comment: Start from $g(x)$, and multiply by $\frac{1-\sqrt{x+1}}{1-\sqrt{x+1}}$ to obtain $f(x)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Third binomial formula: $(a+b)(a-b)=a^2-b^2$
$$\frac{2}{1+\sqrt{x+1}}=\frac{2(1-\sqrt{x+1})}{(1+\sqrt{x+1})(1-\sqrt{x+1})}=\frac{-2 + 2 \sqrt{x+1}}{1^2-(\sqrt{x+1})^2}=\frac{-2 + 2 \sqrt{x+1}}{x}$$

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit on your thought process. Why for example you multiply with (1-sqrt(x+1)). Is this just by practicing a lot that you see this?

Comment: That is the usual procedure to remove square roots from the denominator. I'd say this is a "well-known step".

Comment: Oke thanks, what about starting with g(x) over starting with f(x), do you intuitively choose?

Comment: @GertjanBrouwer The well-known step being referred to is called [*'Rationalizing the denominator'*](https://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/rationalize-denominator.html).

Comment: @GertjanBrouwer I'm sorry I'm not sure if I understood you correctly. What is your question?

Comment: In my example I started working from function f(x) to g(x). You however do it the other way around. What is the reason for this? Is this purely intuition based or maybe the fact that the denominator contains sqrt?

Comment: You usually want to simplify the more complicated term and not make the simple term harder. But of course at the end it doesn't matter what term you modify. Starting with $g(x)$ is just more efficient.

Comment: Alright, that makes sense. I'll try to do it myself on similar questions. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can start with $f(x)$ by doing the following:

$$
\begin{alignat}{1}
f(x) &= \frac{-2 + 2 \sqrt{x+1}}{x} \cdot \frac{(-2-2\sqrt{x+1})}{(-2-2\sqrt{x+1})} = \frac{4-4(x+1)}{-2x-2x\sqrt{x+1}}=\frac{-4x}{-2x\cdot(1+\sqrt{x+1})} 
\\ &= \left(\frac{-2x}{-2x}\right)\cdot \left( \frac{2}{1+\sqrt{x+1}}  \right) = \frac{2}{1+\sqrt{x+1}}=g(x)
\end{alignat}
$$

---

**But what's the idea behind it?**

When solving this type of problem, look at the structure of the functions you are working with. For the functions in your question:

$$
\newcommand{\altfrac}{\genfrac{}{}{0pt}{}}
\begin{alignat}{1}
f(x) = \frac{-2 + 2 \sqrt{x+1}}{x} 
&\altfrac{\leftarrow \text{Square root here}~~~~~}{\leftarrow \text{No square root here}}
\\[8pt]
g(x) = \frac{2}{1+\sqrt{x+1}} 
&\altfrac{\leftarrow \text{No square root here}}{\leftarrow \text{Square root here}~~~~~}
\end{alignat}
$$

Going from $f(x)$ to $g(x)$, you need to make the square root **appear in the denominator**, so a good start would be to **rationalize the numerator** of $f(x)$.

Similary, from $g(x)$ to $f(x)$, you need to make the square root **appear in the numerator**, so a good start would be to **rationalize the denominator** of $g(x)$, as done in *@vitamin d* answer.

Comment: Thanks for writing that up, I see that's a lot more difficult that the other way around.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: consider the following identity
$$
(\sqrt{x+1} + 1)(\sqrt{x+1} - 1) = (\sqrt{x+1})^2 - 1^2 = x + 1 - 1 = x
$$